# ReferenceError: $httpProvider is not defined

Tags: angularjs

This is my script.

```
var rtsTaxi =  angular.module("rtsTaxi",['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);\
rtsTaxi.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProdvider)
{
           $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
           $httpProdvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
           delete $httpProdvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
rtsTaxi.controller("bookingController",function($scope){
var message ="Success";
$scope.bookNow = function()
{
     $http({
     method : 'POST',
     url: 'request-url',
     data: {messages : message},
     header : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset-utf-8'}
     });
};
```

When I run my application, Chrome console give me a Reference error for $httpProvider. I have tried other solutions in StackOverflow but still I am having the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you forgot to inject `$http` in your controller:

```
rtsTaxi.controller("bookingController", function($scope, $http) {
    ...    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in the function argument:

```
tsTaxi.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProdvider)
```

And also, as Mistalis mentioned, you forgot to inject $http into the controller too.